# How to get a specific array from an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot get a single array as an output to array.some

I have tried this code:

```js
data = [{
    Surname: 'Santos',
    Firstname: 'Carlos'
  },
  {
    Surname: 'Reyes',
    Firstname: 'Carla'
  },
  {
    Surname: 'Michael',
    Firstname: 'Lebowski'
  }
];

var found = data.some(function(data) {
  return data.Surname === 'Reyes'
})

console.log(found);
```

The logs I get in return are:

```
0: {Surname: 'Santos', Firstname: 'Carlos'}
1: {Surname: 'Reyes', Firstname: 'Carla"}
2: {Surname: 'Michael', Firstname: 'Lebowski'}
```

My expected logs were:

```
0: {Surname: 'Reyes, Firstname:'Carla'}
```

How can I get my expected logs?

Comment: use `find` instead of `some`

Comment: `filter`, to get an array

Comment: The logs you say you get do not match reality. Logging `found` should only ever show `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.Filter` to get the method and pass your predicate.

```js
data = [
  { Surname: 'Santos',  Firstname: 'Carlos'   },
  { Surname: 'Reyes',   Firstname: 'Carla'    },
  { Surname: 'Michael', Firstname: 'Lebowski' }
];

var foundArray = data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.Surname === 'Reyes';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(foundArray));
```